# Formatting points in TextView for Android

Tags: android, excel, android-sqlite

I'm trying to convert an excel sheet of data into Sqlite database format. However in the excel sheet, there are columns which are in bullet forms. The number of bullet per row is subjective. Therefore i could not assign the columns to achieve this.

Does SQLite support point form formatting or is there any other way i can achieve the same results?

I want to be able to display the data in bullet form in the app itself as well.

Comment: By point form do you mean decimal?  So like 1.23 and you want it to be displayed in the app the same way?  That would be a `float` or `double`.  To display it in a `TextView`, you can use `String.format("My number is %.2f", myNumber")`

Comment: sorry i mean bullet points. Like in a word document u want to illustrate different points with the bullet

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I would suggest using a WebView instead of TextView and using <li> or something for bulleted lists.  It's probably not the best solution but one that might work.